# Force applied per unit area

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, vectors, stress-strain

I am having difficulty in understanding what force applied per unit area means. For example consider a mass $m$ attached to a cylindrical string. When we define stress, we take it to be $\frac{mg}{\pi r^2}$. But the force $F$ is a vector and it can act on one point only,so what do we mean by *it acts on an area*? Now this is seriously raising a lot of doubts in basic issues for me,for example when we push a block across a floor,we apply a force and the block hence goes forward. But this force is a *single* vector and it can only act on a point,so why is it that all the points of the block(e.g the whole block) moves forward instead of the single point where the force was applied? I know the question might be too silly but i need to understand this concept intuitively to fully enjoy physics.

Answer (score 2):

> When we define stress, we take it to be $\frac{mg}{\pi r^2}$

It is the stress in the string at a cross section where the effect of the force can be considered evenly distributed over the cross section.

> But the force $F$ is a vector and it can act on one point only, so what
> do we mean by *it acts on an area*?

The properties of a force vector are magnitude and direction. The vector tells us nothing about how the force is *distributed* in the direction it is applied.

Although a point force is any force where the point of application is considered to be a single point, in reality most forces are technically surface forces where the force is applied over an area. see [http://mechanicsmap.psu.edu/websites/2_equilibrium_concurrent/2-2_point_forces/pointforces.html#:~:text=A%20point%20force%20is%20any,approximated%20as%20a%20point%20force](http://mechanicsmap.psu.edu/websites/2_equilibrium_concurrent/2-2_point_forces/pointforces.html#:%7E:text=A%20point%20force%20is%20any,approximated%20as%20a%20point%20force).

> Now this is seriously raising a lot of doubts in basic issues for
> me,for example when we push a block across a floor,we apply a force
> and the block hence goes forward. But this force is a single vector
> and it can only act on a point

Again, the force vector says nothing about the distribution of the force in the direction it is applied. The fact that force is a vector does not mean it can only act at a point. You need to get that out of your head.

Regarding pushing the box, if you push on the box (a big box) using the side of your body the force is distributed over the area that is greater then if you pushed with the same force with your hand which would be greater than if you tried to push it with your finger. If you tried to push it with your fingernail (close to being a point) it would likely break. In each case the force is the same, but the pressure on your body (and the box) and the magnitude of the localized stress where the force is applied is different.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a force being applied to a point is a simplification to facilitate the understanding of the concepts. Normally we start to learn mechanics studying particles and system of particles, where forces act on some of them.

But for continuous bodies, it is easy to realize the existence of volumetric forces (gravity is distributed for all volume elements) or surface forces (buoyancy for example).